# Insertar datos con clave foránea

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

Buenas tengo un problema en donde no puedo insertar ni editar, estoy tratando de hacer un CRUD php con mysql[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que **curso** y **estado_curso** debe tener datos para poder insertar datos en **alumno**, respecto a **curso** no tengo problemas ya que tiene un formulario donde se crea el curso, el formulario de alumno ahí tengo problemas ya que no tengo datos en **estado_curso** o como podría reestructurar mi diagrama ya que se va insertar y editar que curso este el alumno, sus asistencias, sus notas.
Pd: cada id es autoincremental.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que: *no puedo insertar ni editar*?, considera leer [ask] pues tu pregunta noes muy clara

Comment: puedes dejar el campo de idestado_curso como null en la estructura de tu tabla, así podrás insertar los datos que quieras, pero yo preferiría mejor crear una tabla de relaciones muchos a muchos, donde varios alumnos pueden registrarse en varios cursos.. La nueva tabla sería asi
id
idalumno
idestadocurso

Comment: Por como estan tus tablas, hace falta normalizarlas, la tabla cursos puede ser una relación muchos a muchos con alumnos, notas clases debería de estar ligadas con alumnos y alumnos asistencia debe ser otra tabla muchos a muchos con alumnos y cursos guardando un timestamp en ella, ya en el estado curso se ligaria con cursos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tomar como refencia esta imagen de como pueden ser las relaciones de las tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta estructura, ya podrías insertar la información del alumno, además ya tendrías la posibilidad de agregar a un alumno a uno o más cursos, así como registrar su asistencia a un curso especifico y sus notas.